# How to run two JOptionPane's with threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, joptionpane

I have to set two Dialogs and i want to Stop the first one and then start the second. Can anyone please help me to fix it

```
JOptionPane msg = new JOptionPane("your score is:  " + getScore(), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        final JDialog dlg = msg.createDialog("Game Over");
        dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);



     new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dlg.dispose();

          }
        }).start();
        dlg.setVisible(true);
```

the second Dialog would be the same like

```
JOptionPane message = new JOptionPane("Highscore:  " + getHighscore(), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        final JDialog dialog = message.createDialog("Game Over");
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

now i want to start this Dialog after the first will be closed.

Comment: 1. For the sake of Swing thread safety, use a Swing Timer rather than directly using a background thread. 2. Make it a non-repeating timer. 3. Inside the timer, close/dispose of the current dialog and open the 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommendations:

1. For the sake of Swing thread safety, use a Swing Timer rather than directly using a background thread.
2. Make it a non-repeating timer.
3. Inside the timer's ActionListener, close/dispose of the current dialog and open the 2nd.

e.g., (code not tested)

```
final JDialog myModalDialog = ....;
final JDialog mySecondDialog = ....;
int timerDelay = 3000;
Timer timer = new Timer(timerDelay, e -> {
    myModalDialog.dispose();
    mySecondDialog.setVisible(true);
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
myModalDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Alternatively: use a single dialog and swap views using a [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)